# Split name with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to come up with regular expression which will split full names.

The first part is validation - I want to make sure the name matches the pattern "Name Name" or "Name MI Name", where MI can be one character optionally followed by a period.  This weeds out complex names like "Jose Jacinto De La Pena" - and that's fine.  The expression I came up with is `^([a-zA-Z]+\s)([a-zA-Z](\.?)\s){0,1}([a-zA-Z'-]+)$` and it seems to do the job.

But how do I modify it to split the name into two parts only?  If middle initial is present, I want it to be a part of the first "name", in other words "James T. Kirk" should be split into "James T." and "Kirk".  TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Just add some parenthesis

```
^(([a-z]+\s)([a-z](\.?))\s){0,1}([a-z'-]+)$
```

Your match will be in group 1 now

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"^(([a-z]+\s)([a-z](\.?))\s){0,1}([a-z'-]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Also, I made the regex case insensitive so that you can make it shorter (no a-zA-Z but a-z)

**Update 1**

The number groups don't work well for the case there is no initial so I wrote the regex from sratch

```
^(\w+\s(\w\.\s)?)(\w+)$
```

\w stands for any word charater and this is maybe what you need (you can replace it by a-z if that works better)

**Update 2**

There is a nice feature in C# where you can name your captures

```
^(?<First>\w+\s(?:\w\.\s)?)(?<Last>\w+)$
```

Now you can refer to the group by name instead of number (think it's a bit more readable)

```
var subjectString = "James T. Kirk";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^(?<First>\w+\s(?:\w\.\s)?)(?<Last>\w+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var groups = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups;
var firstName = groups["First"].Value;
var lastName = groups["Last"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by making what is currently your second capturing group a non-capturing group by adding `?:` just before the opening parentheses, and then moving that entire second group into the end of the first group, so it would become the following:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\s(?:[a-zA-Z](\.?)\s)?)([a-zA-Z'-]+)
```

Note that I also replaced the `{0,1}` with `?`, because they are equivalent.

This will result in two capturing groups, one for the first name and middle initial (if it exists), and one for the last name.

Comment: I ended up using this, very slightly modified.  Capturing groups are where it's at - thanks!

Comment: @ChrisH - No problem, since your issue is solved you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/155356) by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this way, but there is a method of doing it without regular expressions.

If the name is in the form of `Name Name` then you could do this:

```
// fullName is a string that has the full name, in the form of 'Name Name'
string firstName = fullName.Split(' ')[0];
string lastName = fullName.Split(' ')[1];
```

And if the name is in the form of `Name MIName` then you can do this:

```
string firstName = fullName.Split('.')[0] + ".";
string lastName = fullName.Split('.')[1].Trim();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the optional part in the first capturing group:

```
(?i)^([a-z]+(?:\s[a-z]\.?)?)\s([a-z'-]+)$
```